# Uniquiness of a linear extension in the application of Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to prove the next exercise:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}.$ Let $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a linear functional on $\mathcal{M}$ with bound $C.$ Prove that there is a unique extension of $f$ to a continuous linear functional on $\mathcal{H}$ with the same bond.

I defined $p:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $p(x)=C||x||.$ Then for every $x\in\mathcal{M},$ $|f(x)|\leq p(x)$ because of $|f(x)|\leq C.$ Then, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, there is a linear extension $\overline{f}:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $|\overline{f}(x)|\leq Cp(x)$ for every $x\in\mathcal{H}.$ Then $|\overline{f}(x)|\leq C$ for every $x\in\mathcal{H}.$

My problem is proving uniqueness. I'm stuck on this. ¿Is there a better way to prove existence and uniqueness easier? Or maybe is better consider another 'p(x)' to prove the stament?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: suppose that there are two extensions and use continuity of $f$ to show they are the same

Comment: Look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532148/the-hahn-banach-theorem-for-hilbert-space